# IndexError: list index out of range, Django

Tags: django

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # get authenticated rfuser
        rfuser = RFUser.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
        print rfuser
        # show info of current user
        project_list = rfuser.project_set.all().order_by('project_name')
#       project_list = RFUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('project_name')
        context_dict = {'projects': project_list}
        return render(request, 'homepage.html', context_dict)
    else:
        return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

#### I get the following error：

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\rfui_web\myaccoutsite\views.py", line 13, in homepage
    rfuser = RFUser.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 295, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

#### list index out of range But can not find why the reason is，Do not know if the index is not due to the array of the relevant value

Comment: I think `RFUser.objects.filter(user=request.user)` returning a empty queryset

Comment: Follow the way you provided after the tips：'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'project_set'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your query is returning an empty queryset. And thus returning IndexError: list index out of range
.If you want o know whether the query gives back something or not first check using:

```
if RFUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
     // then do things which you need
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand what you mean

Comment: RFUser.objects.filter(user=request.user) actually returns an empty queryset. When you try to access the first element of an empty queryset, you get index error, since it does not exist. So in oder to make sure it actually exists, you check it using the above code. Does that make sense?