# getting list index out of range when function is being called Django

Tags: arrays, django, list

I am trying get total here,
whenever i add the new record i got the error
I don't know why i got list index out of range
I m calling the function in `admin.py`

This is my `models.py` file

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
    buyer_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.buyer_name
    
    def buyerdebittotal(self):
        queryset = Buyer.objects.filter(policybuyer__buyer_id = self.id).annotate(total=Sum('policybuyer__buyerdebit',))
        return queryset[0].total     

class Policy(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='policybuyer')
    buyerdebit = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse("insurance:updatepolicy", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871308/10860596

Answer (score 0):

Calling `queryset[0]` on an empty queryset will give you an IndexError. Your code does this in `buyerdebittotal()`, when/if your filter returns an empty set, there is nothing at index 0.
You'll want something more like:

```
def buyerdebittotal(self):
    queryset = Buyer.objects.filter(
            policybuyer__buyer_id = self.id
        ).annotate(total=Sum('policybuyer__buyerdebit',))

    if queryset:
        return queryset[0].total
```